# How can I prove $\sqrt{(111...)+(55...)^2}=5...6$

Tags: calculus, number-theory

The formula in my question can be illustrated as follow:

> $$\sqrt{11+5^2}=6$$
>   $$\sqrt{111+55^2}=56$$ $$\sqrt{1111+555^2}=556$$ $$\sqrt{11111+5555^2}=5556$$ and so on

How can I prove the general formula

> $$\sqrt{\underbrace{11\ldots 1}_{n+1\text{ times}} + (\underbrace{55\ldots 5}_{n\text{ times}})^{2}} = (\underbrace{55\ldots 5}_{n-1\text{ times}}6)^{2}$$

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These equalities are just instances of
$$\sqrt{(2n+1)+n^2}=n+1.$$

Comment: And from here you can do a proof but induction

Comment: @UsernameUnknown: Induction?! How about just squaring both sides instead?

Comment: Well you want to show this is true for any n

Comment: @UsernameUnknown: What, that $(n+1)^2 = n^2+2n+1$? Srsly?

Comment: @TonyK Username Unknown is right. You need induction to prove any statement true for all natural numbers. Just that it being trivial doesn't mean it does not use induction.

Comment: You see proof by induction is what is need if you were to go with this approach

Comment: @Adhvaitha: So how would you prove $(x+1)^2=x^2+2x+1$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$?

Comment: @UsernameUnknown TonyK is right, this is a remarkable identity. Induction is overkill.

Comment: @TonyK Strictly speaking the identity $(x+1)^2 = x^2+2x+1$ must be first proved for $\mathbb{N}$, then for $\mathbb{Z}$, then for $\mathbb{Q}$ and finally use completeness to obtain it for all $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @TonyK How do you prove commutativity, distributivity, and associativity of the arithmetic operators over $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Adhvaitha: No, simple algebra is enough, using the commutativity, distributivity, and associativity of the arithmetic operators. If you claim that these properties must themselves be proved by induction, then I expect your inductive proof of $(n+1)^2=n^2+2n+1$ to contain such proofs! (But that would be silly,right?) (Sorry -- edited and cross-posted.)

Comment: @TonyK Commutativity, distributivity, and associativity of the arithmetic operators over $\mathbb{R}$ needs to proved. How do you prove them? You prove them for $\mathbb{N}$, then for $\mathbb{Z}$, then for $\mathbb{Q}$ and finally for $\mathbb{R}$. This is probably a bit too pedantic, but is the right way to go.

Comment: @Adhvaitha: If you sit down and write out an everyday inductive proof that $(n+1)^2=n^2+2n+1$, you will find yourself using such properties without proof. So why can't I use these properties in a purely algebraic proof?

Comment: @TonyK You can use them. All I am saying is that behind each of these there is induction.

Comment: @Adhvaitha: Well,if that's really all you're saying, I guess we agree...

Answer (score 10):

Hint: rewrite your statements as:

$$6^{2}-5^{2} = 11$$

$$56^{2}-55^{2}=111$$

$$\cdots$$

And prove it using difference of squares (factor the expression).

Comment: If the downvoter would kindly comment, I would be happy to improve my answer.

Comment: Maybe a missing explanation of the relation relation between the LHS and RHS ? (I am not the downvoter)

Comment: Square both sides and subtract? If the downvoter can't see that, I guess we're just going to have some downvotes.

Answer (score 2):

We have
\begin{align}
\underbrace{\dfrac{10^{n+1}-1}9}_{1111\ldots11} + \underbrace{\left(5\cdot \dfrac{10^n-1}9\right)^2}_{555\ldots55^2} & = \dfrac{9\cdot 10^{n+1} - 9 + 5^2 \cdot 10^{2n} - 5^2\cdot 2 \cdot 10^n + 5^2}{9^2}\\
& = \dfrac{5^2 \cdot 10^{2n} + 4 \cdot 10^{n+1} + 16}{9^2}\\
& = \underbrace{\left(5 \cdot \dfrac{10^n-1}9 + 1\right)^2}_{555\ldots56^2}
\end{align}

Comment: Correct but the "hard" way.

Comment: @YvesDaoust "hard" is a relative term and highly person dependent.